# VSCode : It is not showing java script functions in intellisense e.g. .toLowerCase

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code is an amazing text editor but I am facing some issues.

**ISSUE**

VS Code not showing IntelliSense for basic javascript functions like `myVariable.toLowerCase();`

[image]

Please let me know if there is any solution for this.

*Thanks VS Code team for making development beautiful!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm on the VSCode team.

We cannot infer the types of JavaScript variables like `categoryName` in many cases, so we cannot know that `toLowerCase` is a valid method on `categoryName`. There are a few ways to fix this:

- Use jsdoc to specify the argument type:

  ```
  /**
   * @param {string} categoryName
   */
  function foo(categoryName){
      // `string` member completions avalible here
  }
  ```
- Add a guard to the function:

  ```
  function foo(categoryName){
      if (typeof categoryName !== 'string')
          return
      // `string` member completions available here
  }
  ```
- Use TypeScript or Flow types

  ```
  function foo(categoryName: string){
      // `string` member completions available here
  }
  ```

Hope that helps.